# finding a specfic value in a vector based on the value of another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector called a_vector:

`a_vector<-sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)`

And I wrote a function called my_function

```
my_function<-function(a){
  a*3-2
}
```

and I used this to create a new vector called b_vector:

`b_vector<-my_function(a_vector)`

Now, I want to find a specific value in the a_vector that results in a specific number in the b_vector after applying the my_function. For example, I want to retrieve the value in the a_vector that returns 148 in the b_vector. I tried the following codes and they did not work and I have no idea what to do. I'd appreciate any helps.

`new<-a_vector[b_vector==148]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `a_vector` result is not reproducible. So I use `set.seed` first, then run the following.

```
set.seed(3) # this ensures reproducibility
a_vector <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)

my_function <- function(a){
        a*3-2
}

b_vector <- my_function(a_vector)
```

The 8th element in the `b_vector` is 58. The following code finds the corresponding element in the `a_vector`, which is 20:

```
a_vector[which(b_vector == 58)]

[1] 20
```